# Как заставить мобильный браузер запоминать "Полную версию сайта"?

Tags: viewport

При включении галочки в мобильном браузере "Версия для ПК" происходит переход с мобильной версии сайта на десктопную. Но если переходить по некоторым страницам сайта, то иногда эта галочка слетает и прогружается обычная мобильная версия и снова приходится включать эту галочку. Т.е. мобильный браузер почему-то не на всех страницах запоминает эту опцию. С чем это связано и можно ли как-то на это повлиять?